# Quarto: `project: type: book`-like project organization, but for articles?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

I'm writing a lengthy article using `quarto` and multiple profiles (think `full` & `short` versions), which use different subsets of content provided in individual `*.qmd` files.

The quarto project type `book` seems perfect for this, as different `book: chapters: *` definitions in profile-specific `_quarto-<PROFILE>.yml` nicely do the job of profile-individual input file selection and produce joined output.

The PDF/LaTeX output, however is distinctly book-like (uses KOMA-Script's `scrreprt`) and not easily forced towards an article layout - see demonstration code below.

[Includes](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/includes.html) are a way out but distinctly less elegant then in-header input file definition.

Is there currently a way to achieve book-like project organization for articles? Is that on any roadmap? May it be put there?

**Demonstration/Solution Attempts**

- Base line behavior:

  1. Create book project:

     ```
     SHELL> quarto create-project mybook --type book
     ```
  2. Render:

     ```
     SHELL> cd mybook
     SHELL> quarto render --to=pdf
     ```
  3. Inspect pdf in `_book` subdirectory - nice but bookish.
- Attempt to force style change by switching to KOMA-Script's `scrartcl` document class:

  1. Edit `_quarto.yml` as follows:

     ```
     format:
       html:
         theme: cosmo
       pdf:
         # documentclass: scrreprt
         documentclass: scrartcl
     ```
  2. Render:

     ```
     SHELL> quarto render --to=pdf
     ```
  3. **ERROR**:

     ```
     ...
     compilation failed- error
     Undefined control sequence.
     <argument> \chapter 
              *{Preface}\label {preface}
     l.187 \chapter*{Preface}\label{preface}}


     see /tmp/mybook/index.log for more information.
     ```

     --> `chapter` is undefined in the context of `scrartcl`
- Setting `project: type: default` instead of `book` leads to loss of `chapter` integration into a single output PDF and all `*.qmd`s are being rendered into individual output files.

Comment: When using the `documentclass: scrartcl` route in the context of `project: type: book`, explicitly providing a bare bones [pandoc template](https://quarto.org/docs/journals/templates.html) that forces scrartcl does **not** help, as quarto keeps producing LaTeX code with `scrreprt`-specificity (`chapter` etc.).